# LG phone camera. How to interpret this EXIF User Comment metadata? "0 FM0 CR0 Prmid2 mxDrkA..."

Tags: metadata, smartphone, cameraphones

What do the following numbers and abbreviations mean? Photos taken with LG phone cameras tend to have information like this in the "User Comment" metadata:

`0 FM0 CR0 Prmid2 mxDrkA2.07 mxBrtA0.22 mxPkNSat1.04 dr46.43 br3.56 wdr18.68 wbr1.47 sbr0.34 ldr49.83 lp46.0 [f0] 000000000bfalic 00000`

(this example is from the extended details of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:COLORFUL_SPRING_BOUQUET.jpg#metadata (not my photo))

Comment: Unless someone here has some information... I'd suggest you ask LG support directly. I wasn't able to find any info on any of these strings.